# Porting an Objective-C block to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am porting a game I made in Objective c to swift as it is a good way to learn how to port something and how to mix swift with objective c and objective c with swift.

But after lots of searching I can't find how to port this line of code:

```
GCControllerDirectionPadValueChangedHandler dpadMoveHandler = 
 ^(GCControllerDirectionPad *dpad, float xValue, float yValue) { }
```

Only thing I found was this piece of code from apple:

**Swift**

```
typealias GCControllerDirectionPadValueChangedHandler = 
 (GCControllerDirectionPad!, CFloat, CFloat) -> Void
```

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
typedef void (^GCControllerDirectionPadValueChangedHandler)
   (GCControllerDirectionPad *dpad, float xValue, float yValue)
```

--

This is the code I've tried so far, but with no luck.

```
var dpadMoveHandler: GCControllerDirectionPadValueChangedHandler = 
   (#dpad:GCControllerDirectionPad, #xValue:CFloat, #yValue:CFloat)  {

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line declares an Objc block. The typealias you're looking at in Swift is a closure type. The equivalent code would be this:

```
var dpadMoveHandler:GCControllerDirectionPadValueChangedHandler = 
  { 
     (dpad:GCControllerDirectionPad!, xValue:CFloat, yValue:CFloat) -> () in 
     return 
  }
```

Read about Swift closures [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Closures.html).